# Hidden stair case trouble

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

[image]

Heres what im working with. I am trying to make a hidden staircase. The idea is that the iron block is flush with the floor, then gets pulled down and replaced by the stair. But I dont want the vertical piston to extend the stair block. so the iron is pulled down and moved to the side and the stair is moved in but not extended up.

Comment: Update: i decided to separate this into two different systems... One being the iron block being pulled down and moved to the side, and the stair being pushed to the middle. The problem I am having now is that I dont know how to to make the stair extend in after the iron is moved, but then move out before the iron is moved in.

Answer (score 1):

easiest and most compact I could make was 6x1x2 with an observer coming in clutch

Answer (score 1):

A YouTuber has come up with a way to do this in a fairly compact manner. It doesn't use actual staircases, but it mat be a place to start.